# How to get for sale posts from a group using facebook api

Tags: facebook, api

Using the Group/feed method we can get the posts from a specific group

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/group/feed

but how to filter returned items so we only get for sale posts or even how to check if the post is a for sale post or not?

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: @WizKid could you please hint on where can I create or track a feature request for this

Comment: @atef Did you get sale post into feed? because I'm trying to get sale posts but its not fetching any of sale post. All other posts are being fetched.

Answer (score 4):

You could check whether the permalink_url property has a query string parameter "sale_post_id".

Comment: After the recent security upgrades for Facebook API, how do we do it now?

Comment: The URL property hasn't changed after the recent API changes. This still works